# Oracle materialized view last FINISHED refresh

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

How to find out if changes made at known time in underlying table are already available in fast refreshing materialized view?

So far:

**all_mview_analysis.LAST_REFRESH_DATE** - this seems to be the start time of the refresh not end time? Is this value written when refresh is started or when it is finished?

**all_mview_analysis.INCREFRESHTIM** - docs say this is "Approximate refresh time, in seconds, for fast refresh". Approximate is not enough.

**In other words:** I have changed data at time x. I need to query if those changes made at time x are already included in materialized view or not. I want to wait as much as needed but as little as possible.

Database: Oracle 11g.

Comment: What are your requirements? Why do you need to know that? Materialized views are very efficient for quick data access in environments where the exact delay is not very important (e.g. data ware houses). Usually it suffices to say "refreshes every hour, last refresh started xx:xx". Did you consider an `ON COMMIT REFRESH` materialized view?

Comment: Materialized view reflects user access rights in my system. The purpose of using materialized view is to be able to verify user access rights very fast.
Now, when data changes I need to send messages to other systems. 
But I am not allowed to do this before it is sure that the changes in user access rights(caused by changed data I mentioned before) are included in materialized view.

Comment: ON COMMIT REFRESH materialized view - as much as I understand at the moment, the commit will not be finished before the materialized view has finished refreshing? If so this is not an option for me. There are very high expectations on the performance of the operations that change data.

Comment: Yes, `ON COMMIT REFRESH` will slow down the transaction. The impact for a fast refreshing materialized view is usually not very high, but still noticeable. Maybe the columns `STALENESS` and `STALE_SINCE` are useful to you? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-8B9432B5-6B66-411A-936E-590D9D7671E9.htm#REFRN20139

Comment: Alternatively, can you build in an on demand refresh right before you send out messages to other systems? A call to `dbms_mview.refresh('MVIEW_NAME')` will accomplish that.

Comment: Yes, actually I am already using this forced refresh approach in my tests before checking the changes in user access rights after executing operations that change data.
But in production I have about 30 requests in second that cause the generation of the messages. I am wondering if it will be OK to force the refresh for example 30 times in second?

Comment: 30 times per second is probably too much. Refreshes are serialized, so if you know the time it takes to refresh, you can calculate how many times per second you can do that. Does this also mean that you want to send out updates to other systems 30 times per second? That also looks like a lot to me.

Comment: Correction: full refresh is serialized. I'm not sure about fast refresh.

Comment: I was wrong about massive simultaneous materialized view refresh forcing. Actually I have built a buffer table where the needs of message generation are stored. The process that reads next row from that table and generates messages runs with limited number of threads. So if I keep the number of threads low enough there should not be too many forced refreshes in unit of time. 
Forced refresh feels much more reliable than querying the refreshness. I   think I will at least try this approach.